# How do I write a C# method that takes a variable number of arguments?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to send a variable number of arguments to a method?

For instance if I want to write a method that would concatenate many `string[]` objects into one string, but I wanted it to be able to accept arguments without knowing how many I would want to pass in, how would I do this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you pass an IEnumerable?

Comment: That infinite data structure is going to take a while to iterate over...

Comment: The title should probably say variable as opposed to infinite.

Comment: @David: Maybe you shouldn't be cracking jokes then.  :P

Comment: @JohnOpincar I could have used IEnumerable, and it did cross my mind however in circumstances where I have multiple string[] objects I would have to write code to assign them to an IEnumerable object, so by using the params keyword (thanks for the tip everyone) I save a few lines.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You would do this as:

```
string ConcatString(params string[] arguments)
{
   // Do work here
}
```

This can be called as:

```
string result = ConcatString("Foo", "Bar", "Baz");
```

For details, see [params (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx).

---

FYI - There is already a [`String.Concat(params object[] args)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9c94ey1.aspx) - it will concatenate any set of objects by calling ToString() on each.  So for this specific example, this is probably not really that useful.

Answer (score 4):

[Use the `params` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to do that:

```
public static string ConvertToOneString(params string[] list) 
{

    string result = String.Empty;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.Length ; i++ )
    {
        result += list[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
string s = "hello"
string a = "world"
string result = ConvertToOneString(s, a);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily create a method that takes an arbitrary number of arguments (including zero), using the [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) keyword:

```
public static void UseParams(params int[] list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        Console.Write(list[i] + " ");
}
```

You can even pass an array to this method instead of a list of parameters, and the method will work exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

very easy to do so using [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keyword

```
void ConcatString(params String[] strArray)
{ 
    foreach (String s in strArray)
    {
        // do whatever you want with all the arguments here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can use [**params**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for that

Answer (score 2):

Use `params`:

```
void YourMethod(params string[] infiniteArgs) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string MyConcat(params string[] values)
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var v in values)
       s.Append(v);
    return s.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't mean infinite (the answer to that question is no) but you do mean 'variable'. Here is your answer (yes): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/08/05/209384.aspx

Comment: Why the downvote? Perhaps the voter didn't see the history of the question. If so, please review and remove the downvote if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, infinite - no (there is a finite amount of memory available, for example).

Unknown at design-time, yes.

The classic example of this is how it's handled on a Console application.

http://dotnetperls.com/main

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t(VS.71).aspx